# How to use Tahoma 8 bold on Processing.js?

Tags: javascript, html, processing, processing.js

Processing.js documentation does not explain how you use a web-safe font with bold style. I have already tried `loadFont("tahoma_bold.ttf")` placing a font I downloaded on the same folder as the script `(/project/main.js and /project/tahoma_bold.ttf)`. I have also tried `/project/data/tahoma_bold.ttf`. How do you do it?

Comment: Have you tried this link? http://processingjs.org/reference/font/

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan eh yea, I've read every piece of related documentation already. No luck.

Comment: have you placed it in the same directory as your index.html, because browsers resolve links relative to the page, not relative to "the sketch"?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans yes, everything is in a single folder.

Comment: In that case I guess the three questions are 1) did you preload the font with the font directive, 2) did you also use createFont() (both of which the docs tell you to do, http://processingjs.org/reference/font), and 3) do you get any console errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey so I ran into a similar problem a couple of months ago when I tried the same thing but a little more complicated since I was running it in a web2py page. Here's the [link to my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18267517/using-custom-fonts-for-processing-js-in-web2py/18267518#18267518) for that.

And here is the simple answer I can think of for your question: instead of doing a loadfont, try:

```
textFont(createFont("/tahoma_bold.ttf",14));
```

One of two things will happen. If it works, congrats! If not, you need to add or remove parts of the path (try messing with backslashes) because it's likely the font can't be found. If you get some sort of result and comment back, I can keep helping you figure this one out.

Hope it works!